# Unable to update from version 2.1.1 to 2.2 preview in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-studio-2.1, android-studio-2.2

I am using android studio version 2.1.1 from developer channel. I got update notification from android 2.2 preview in canary channel. But I am not able to directly update 2.1.1 to 2.2 preview. **It asks for separate download of version 2.2 preview of android studio.**

**Can anyone help if i don't want to separately download android studio 2.2 preview and want to directly update over android studio 2.1.1?**

Here is attached screenshot for the same.

[image]
If i click on Download button it takes me to the downloads site instead of direct update over 2.1.1

Comment: I dont know why but this is the only way to update from one stable version to another. I have same problem and i just downloaded new AS.

Comment: @shvet- android studio 2.2 is not a stable version. Its preview version

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using stable or beta version, you will not be able to directly update it. However you can update it to any beta/stable version but not to the preview version.

It is recommended to run preview version stand alone, so it will not affect your current stable/beta version.

> We are not offering patches to ensure we do not disrupt your current
>   stable configurations with our first 2.2 preview. Please download a
>   full IDE image linked below to ensure you have the correct JDK bundled with the installation.
>
> Note : We recommend you keep 2.1.1 and 2.2 Preview 1 installed side by side

Comment: Does that mean that if i directly want to update over 2.1.1 stable version i have to wait for 2.2 stable version ? Can it directly update then?

Comment: yes you have to wait for 2.2 stable/beta version, and it is recommended to wait for stable/beta version, because preview versions are just for testing purpose and to let people know about new features.

Comment: I have installed side by side stable 2.1.2 and preview 2.2, but I face that 2.2 disrupt my stable 2.1.2 version. Its change path to JDK, and keep last opened project. (I have resolved keeping last open project by turning-off this funtionality)

Answer (score 3):

Yes, to update to Android Studio 2.2, you need to download only IDE file from the [download site](http://tools.android.com/download/studio/canary/latest).Just replace downloaded IDE file to your existing IDE file.

Answer (score 1):

if you are updating through canary/dev channel than you will have to download whole file of android studio, you will be redirected to download page of studio

[image]

if you are updating through stable channel than you get option for

**update and restart**

[image]

> We are not
>   offering patches to ensure we do not disrupt your current stable
>   configurations with our first 2.2 preview. Please download a full IDE
>   image linked below to ensure you have the correct JDK bundled with the
>   installation. Note We recommend you keep 2.1.1 and 2.2 Preview 1
>   installed side by side; they already use separate settings and cache
>   directories. [More information on how to install multiple versions
>   simultaneously.](http://tools.android.com/tips/using-multiple-android-studio-versions)