# Android Studio update from 2.1.1 to 2.1.2

Tags: android, android-studio, upgrade

I have 2.1.1 and I want to update to 2.1.2 (Android Studio show me the notification of the new version)

The update notification dialog show me the following options: "Remind me later", "Download", "Release Notes" and "Ignore this update". It doesn´t show me "Update and Restart"

If I click "download" it redirects me to the IDE download page. 
It should download a patch and install it automatically? Am I wrong?

Thx in advanced

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android Studio update issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21422545/android-studio-update-issue)

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37451724/unable-to-update-from-version-2-1-1-to-2-2-preview-in-android-studio

Comment: thx @YogeshRathi, I tried that but thats not the problem, in fact I never clicked the "Ignore" option, any other ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because of a known bug with Android Studio, the bug prevents you from updating Android Studio without downloading the whole thing.

So Unfortunately, **you must download the complete IDE**. Google is aware of this and is trying to fix it.

Comment: Thx a lot @AbAppletic, is there a way to do it without loosing my previuos conf?

Comment: Don't worry about it, the installer asks you if you want to restore your config